# Statements regarding relations in R

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Suppose $\rho$ is a relation on $R$. I want to verify whether the following statements are true. Looks simple but proving them seems to be difficult for me.

- $\rho\circ\rho$ is a subset of $\rho$
- $\rho\circ\rho=\rho$ implies $\rho=i_{D(\rho)}$ ($D(\rho)$ being the domain of $\rho$)
- $\rho=\rho^{-1}$ implies $\rho=i_{D(\rho)}$

I believe the second point is false considering the counter example constant function but I need help with the other statements.

Comment: By relation, do you mean equivalence relation, or any binary relation?

Comment: Any binary relation

Comment: What does $i_{D(\rho)}$ mean?

Comment: identity function with the domain of ρ

Comment: I notice that your second and fourth statements are the same. Is one of them mis-typed?

Comment: @CameronBuie it was a duplicate thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of them are false.

For the first, let $\rho = \{(a,b),\,(b,c)\}$

For the second, let $\rho = \{(1,1),\,(3,3),\,(1,3),\,(3,1)\}$

For the third, let $\rho = \{(0,1),\,(1,0)\}$

Comment: When ρ={(1,1),(3,3),(1,3),(3,1)}, $ρ^{-1}=ρ$ right?

Comment: @RajindaWickrama Oh yes. So the $\rho$ of the second statement serves as a counterexample for the third as well.

Comment: @RajindaWickrama Why would you bring up ${\rho}^{-1}\circ\rho$? None of your statements mention it.

Comment: Sorry that was in addition to the above statements. Do you think $ρ^{-1}oρ$=i?

Comment: @RajindaWickrama If you're talking about the second example then no. $\rho^{-1} \circ\rho=\rho$

Answer (score 0):

For an arbitrary binary relation, the first is false: if $\rho=\{(0,1), (2,0)\}$, then $(2,1)\in\rho\circ\rho$.

Regarding the second, I don't quite see what $i_{D(\rho)}$ is... actually, what is $D(\rho)$ itself — a subset of $\mathbb R$, or of $\mathbb R^2$)?

Assuming $D(\rho)$ is the subset of $\mathbb R$ consisting of all the first components of $\rho$, then consider$\rho=\{(0,1)\}\cup\{(x,x)\}_{x\in\mathbb{R}}$. You do have $\rho\circ\rho=\rho$.

Comment: D(ρ) is the domain of  ρ which is a subset of R. $i_{D(ρ)}$ is the identity function with the domain of ρ

Comment: Also, to proceed with the following points, how do you define $\rho^{-1}$ in general ($\rho$ is not even a function)?

Comment: @ClementC. I think that is the inverse relation of $\rho$.

Comment: Yes it is the inverse relation

Comment: So the third point is false too. Take $\rho=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$.